# 1st brother, 2nd brother, if the next in line is a girl, should i refer to her as 3rd sister or 1st sister?

Tags: word-request

Pretty much the title. I'm thinking of writing about a family or organization that refer to their members as to 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc... followed by gender. Is it alright to refer to them as is or will it confuse (maybe just me) a lot of people? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first sister, in everyday use. Or third child or third sibling.

Saying third sister in a description of a family will usually be taken to imply there are a first and second sister.

Comment: Note too that saying "first sister" implies you have more than one. Othewise it is just "sister" although that does not mean you have *only* one sister.

Comment: For many sisters this works but for two or three sisters I think, oldest sister, middle sister, youngest sister is more comprehensible.  For one sister, just sister.